# The generalized continuum hypothesis can't fail first at $\omega_{\omega_{1}}$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, infinitary-combinatorics

I am willing to prove that the GCH cannot first fail at a singular cardinal. For this purpouse I am following the strategy outlined by Kunen in his 2013 book (see Exercises III.6.16-6.17-6.18-6.19).
I have not any problems regarding to the first exercise (III.6.16) however I am not able to take advantage of the hints from the exercises 6.17-6.18. I write down both.

A family of functions $\mathcal{F}\subset \lambda^\kappa$ is a eventually disjoint family (edf) if $|\{\alpha<\kappa:\,f(\alpha)= g(\alpha)\}|<\kappa$ for every $f,g\in \mathcal{F}$ and $f\neq g$

**Exercise III 6.17** Assume that $\lambda=\omega_{\omega_1}$, $\forall\alpha<\omega_1\,[2^{\aleph_\alpha}<\lambda]$, $\mathcal{F}\subset \lambda^{\omega_1}$ an eventually disjoint family, and $\{\alpha<\omega_1:\,f(\alpha)<g(\alpha)\}$ is stationary for every $f\in\mathcal{F}$, where $g:\omega_1\rightarrow\lambda$ and $g(\alpha)<\omega_{\alpha+1}$ for all $\alpha$. Prove that $|\mathcal{F}|\leq \lambda$.

**My Attempt:** Let's denote by $S_f=\{\alpha<\omega_1:\,f(\alpha)<g(\alpha)\}$. For every $\alpha\in S_f$ we have $|f(\alpha)|\leq |g(\alpha)|\leq \omega_\alpha$ since $g(\alpha)<\omega_{\alpha+1}$ and therefor $|f(\alpha)|=\omega_{f'(\alpha)}$ where $f'(\alpha)<\alpha$. Now applying Fodor's Lemma to $f'$ and $S_f$ we can find an stationary set $S'_f\subset S_f$ such that $S'_f=\{\alpha<\omega_1: |f(\alpha)|=\omega_{\beta_0}\}$. It is clear by the hypothesis $\forall\alpha<\omega_1\,[2^{\aleph_\alpha}<\lambda]$ that $|Club(\omega_1)|\leq \lambda$. So my question is, is the map $f\mapsto S'_f$ injective? If it would not be the case, how can we prove that $|\mathcal{F}|\leq \lambda$?
Also, if the answer to the first question would be affirmative, I would like to know why it is necessary to assume $2^{\aleph_\alpha}<\lambda$ further than $\alpha>1$.

**Exercise III 6.18** Assume that $\lambda=\omega_{\omega_1}$, $\forall\alpha<\omega_1\,[2^{\aleph_\alpha}=\aleph_{\alpha+1}]$. Prove that $2^\lambda=\lambda^+$.

**My Attempt** By the hypothesis and the Exercise III-6.16 we can take an edf family $\mathcal{F}\subset \lambda^{\omega_1}$ of cardinality $2^\lambda$ such that $f(\alpha)<\omega_{\alpha+1}$ for all $f\in\mathcal{F}$ and $\alpha<\omega_1$. Given $f,g\in\mathcal{F}$ two different functions, it can be shown that $f<^* g\leftrightarrow \{\alpha\in\omega_1:\,f(\alpha)<g(\alpha)\}\in Club(\omega_1)$ is a totally order. Now given $g\in\mathcal{F}$ consider the edf $\mathcal{F}_g=\{f\in \mathcal{F}: f<^* g\}$. Applying Exercise III.6.17 we conclude that $|\mathcal{F}_g|\leq \lambda$. Since $<^*$ is a totally order given two diferent functions $g,g'\in\mathcal{F}$ then $\mathcal{F}_g\neq \mathcal{F}_{g'}$. Is there any way to take profit of this information to prove the inequality $|\mathcal{F}|\leq \lambda^+$?

Any help or hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: In general, the map $f \mapsto S_{f}'$ is not injective and you need finer control in your coding. I provided an unrefined example below.

Comment: By the way, it's not true that $<^{*}$ is a strict total order on $\mathcal F$. Let $f,g \colon \omega_{1} \to \lambda$ be such that $f(\alpha+1) = \omega_{\alpha}$, $g(\alpha+1) = \omega_{\alpha}+1$ for all $\alpha < \omega_{1}$ and such that $f(\alpha) = \omega_{\alpha}+1$ and $g(\alpha) = \omega_{\alpha}$ for all limit $\alpha < \omega_{1}$.

Comment: In the first sentence of the question, you probably meant not just "singular cardinal" but "singular cardinal of uncountable cofinality." Without the cofinality restriction, the result wouldn't be true (unless some relatively mild large cardinals turn out to be inconsistent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Exercise III 6.17:**
For $f \in \mathcal F$ let
$S_{f} := \{ \alpha < \omega_{1} \mid f(\alpha) < g(\alpha) \}$. First
consider the case that $g \colon \omega_{1} \to \lambda$ satisfies
$g(\alpha) = \omega_{\alpha}$ for every $\alpha < \omega_{1}$. By
Fodor, we may, for each $f \in F$, choose some stationary
$T_{f} \subseteq S_{f}$ and some cardinal $\kappa_{f} < \lambda$ such
that $f(\alpha) < \kappa_{f}$ for all $\alpha \in T_{f}$. For each
$f \in \mathcal F$ let
$f^{*} := (\kappa_{f}, T_{f}, \{ (\alpha,f(\alpha)) \mid \alpha \in
T_{f}\})$. Let $f,g \in \mathcal F$ be distinct. Since $\mathcal F$ is
an eventually disjoint family, there is some $\gamma < \omega_{1}$ such
that
$\{\alpha < \omega_{1} \mid f(\alpha) = g(\alpha) \} \subseteq
\gamma$. Since $T_{f}, T_{g}$ are stationary and thus unbounded in
$\omega_{1}$, this implies
$\{(\alpha,f(\alpha)) \mid \alpha \in T_{f} \} \neq \{ (\alpha,
g(\alpha)) \mid \alpha \in T_{g} \}$, i.e. $f^{*} \neq g^{*}$. In
particular, the map $\mathcal F \ni f \mapsto f^{*}$ is injective. Now
$f^{*} \in \lambda \times \mathcal P(\omega_{1}), \bigcup_{\alpha <
  \omega_{1}} \mathcal P(\omega_{1} \times \omega_{\alpha})$ and thus
$| \mathcal F | \le | \lambda \times \omega_{1} \times \bigcup_{\alpha
  < \omega_{1}} \mathcal P(\omega_{1} \times \omega_{\alpha}) | \le
\sup_{\alpha < \omega_{1}} \lambda \cdot \omega_{1} \cdot
2^{\omega_{\alpha}} \le \lambda.$ (Here we use that
$2^{\omega_{\alpha}} \le \lambda$ for all $\alpha < \omega_{1}$.)

The proof for general $g \colon \omega_{1} \to \lambda$ such that
$g(\alpha) < \omega_{\alpha+1}$ for all $\alpha < \omega_{1}$ is
similar. For each $\alpha < \omega_{1}$ fix an injection
$\Gamma_{\alpha} \colon g(\alpha) \to \omega_{\alpha}$. Let $S_{f}$ be
as above. For each $\alpha \in S_{f}$, we have that
$\Gamma_{\alpha}(f(\alpha)) < \Gamma_{\alpha}(g(\alpha)) <
\omega_{\alpha}$ and there is hence some $\kappa_{f} < \lambda$ and
some stationary $T_{f} \subseteq S_{f}$ such that for all $\alpha \in
T_{f} \colon \Gamma_{\alpha}(f(\alpha)) < \kappa_{f}$. Now let $f^{*}
= (\kappa_{f}, T_{f}, \{ (\alpha, \Gamma_{\alpha}(f(\alpha))) \mid
\alpha \in T_{f} \})$. As before, the map $\mathcal F \ni f \mapsto
f^{*}$ is injective and thus implies that $| \mathcal F | \le \lambda$.

**Exercise III 6.18:**  Let $\mathcal F \subseteq ^{\omega_{1}}\lambda$ be an eventually
  disjoint family of size $2^{\lambda}$ such that for all $f \in
  \mathcal F \forall \alpha < \omega_{1} \colon f(\alpha) <
  \omega_{\alpha +1}$. For $f,g \in \mathcal F$ write $f <^{*} g$ iff $\{
  \alpha < \omega_{1} \mid f(\alpha) < g(\alpha) \}$ contains a club and
  let $<^{*} \subseteq \prec$  be a strict total order on $\mathcal
  F$. For $g \in \mathcal F$ let $F_{g} := \{ f \in \mathcal F \mid f
  \prec g \}$. Let $f \prec g$. I claim that $\{ \alpha < \omega_{1} \mid f(\alpha) <
  g(\alpha) \}$ is stationary in $\omega_{1}$:

Suppose not. Then there is some club $C \subseteq \omega_{1}$ such
  that for all $\alpha \in C \colon f(\alpha) \ge g(\alpha)$. Since $f,g
  \in \mathcal F$ are distinct and $\mathcal F$ is an eventually
  disjoint family, the set $\{ \alpha  \in C \mid g(\alpha) < f(\alpha)
  \}$ contains some club $D \subseteq \omega_{1}$, witnessing that $g
  \prec f$. Contradiction.

We may now apply Exercise III 6.17: For each $g \in \mathcal F$, we
  now know that $F_{g}$ has size $\le \lambda$. Now, recursively
  construct a sequence $(g_{\alpha} \mid \alpha < \lambda^{+})$ as
  follows: Pick any $g_{0} \in \mathcal F$. Given $(g_{\alpha} \mid
  \alpha < \gamma)$ for some $\gamma < \lambda$, we have that $\bigcup
  \{ F_{g_{a}} \mid \alpha < \gamma \}$ has size at most $| \lambda | \cdot
  \gamma = \lambda < 2^{\lambda}$. There is hence some $g_{\gamma} \in
  \mathcal F$ such that for all $\alpha < \gamma \colon g_{\alpha} \prec
  g_{\lambda}$. This finishes our construction.

I now claim that $\bigcup \{ \mathcal F_{g_{\alpha}} \mid \alpha < \lambda^{+} \}=
  \mathcal F$.

Suppose not. Then there is some $f \in \mathcal F$ such that
  $g_{\alpha} \prec f$ for all $\alpha < \lambda^{+}$ (by the totality of $\prec$). Hence $\mathcal
  F_{f}$ has size $\ge \lambda^{+}$. Contradiction.

We thus have that $\mathcal F = \bigcup \{g_{\alpha} \mid \alpha <
  \lambda^{+}\}$ has size at most $\lambda \cdot \lambda^{+} =
  \lambda^{+}$. In particular, we have $2^{\lambda} = \lambda^{+}$.

Comment: Thank you very much @Stefan! But regarding to the first exercise; why it is needed in the construction of $f^*$ the selection of the cardinal $\kappa_f$? It wouldn't be enough with taking $f^*=\{(\alpha,f(\alpha)):\alpha\in T_f\}$ and proving that $f\mapsto f^*$ is injective between $\mathcal{F}$ and $\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_1}\mathcal{P}(\omega_1\times\omega_\alpha)$ ?

Comment: @Antoine Sure. I only included $\kappa_{f}$ in my coding to emphasize that $f$ is bounded below $\lambda$ on this stationary set. If you took $\kappa_{f}$ as the supremum of $\operatorname{ran} (f \restriction T_{f})$ (which you may obviously do), then you can read off $\kappa_{f}$ from $T_{f}$ and $f$.

Comment: Thank you once again @Stefan :) In the general setting, where is needed the condition of uncountable cofinality?

Comment: @Antoine The problem is that 'clubs' are ill-behaved on cardinals of countable cofinality. Take for example a strictly increasing and cofinal sequence $(\kappa_n \mid n < \omega)$ in some cardinal $\kappa$ of countable cofinality. Then $\{ \kappa_n \mid n < \omega \}$ is a club that does not contain a single limit point (let me stress that is may contain limit ordinals - these are different notions). In particular, there are disjoint clubs on $\kappa$.

Comment: Note that in this case there are no stationary sets...

Comment: OK, thank you @Stefan. So, in this case, for example, would $\{\kappa_{2n}\}_n$ and $\{\kappa_{2n+1}\}_n$ be to disjoint club sets?

Comment: @Antoine Yes, they would.

Comment: I know that it is possible to violate GCH at first time at a regular cardinal using forcing. However, I can't see where the singularity of the cardial comes into play in the proof. In other words, why this proof can't be reproduced for a regular cardinal?

Comment: @Antoine For regular cardinals $\lambda$, we would have to consider stationary subsets of $\operatorname{cf}(\lambda) = \lambda$ instead and there are just too many of them. (Well, it's consistent that there are too many.)